# fatal error Function name must be a string

Tags: php

thanks to the folks who answered my last question

i keep getting this error: Function name must be a string in /home/pulsergf/public_html/these/vars.php on line 4

```
<?
$array = array('555', '666', 'aaa', 'bbb', '777', '888');
$rand_index = mt_rand(0, count($array) / 2 - 1) * 2;
$define('BOUGHT','echo "$array[$rand_index]";');
$define('SOLD','echo "$array[$rand_index+1]";');
?>
```

so it needs to choose the pair in the array for BOUGHT and SOLD but i keep getting this error. thanks

Answer (score 1):

use `define` instead of `$define`

`$define()` indicates a [variable function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php), which means it takes the string value of `$define` and tries to call the function with the same name as that string.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `$` in front of `define`.

**Why?**

When you precede `define` with `$` followed by a few parameters within `(...)`, it is interpreted as a [**variable function**](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php). Since the variable `$define` is not defined it becomes effective equivalent to calling a function without the function name.