# Fatal error: Function name must be a string

Tags: php

What does the "function name must be a string error" message mean?

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/speedycm/public_html/speedyautos/admincp/admincar_cls.php on line 222

Lines 190-222 in admincar_cls.php reads:

```
$this->_db->query($sql);

if ($this->_db->num_rows())
{
    $rows = $this->_db->_fetch_row('DB_FETCH_ASSOC');
    $this->ownername = $rows['ownername'];
    $this->owner_email = $rows['owner_email'];
    $this->city = $rows['city'];
    $this->state_id = $rows['state_id'];
    //$this->caption=$rows[caption];
    $this->car_features = stripslashes($rows['features']);
    $this->year = $rows['year'];
    $this->make = $rows['make'];
    $this->model = $rows['model'];
    $this->color = $rows['color'];
    $this->seller = $rows['userid'];
    $this->dateadded = date("m/d/Y", $rows['date_added']);
    $this->miles = $rows['miles'];
    $this->city = $rows['city'];
    $this->state = $rows['state_name'];
    $this->owner_id = $rows['owner_id'];
    $this->cstatus = $rows['cstatus'];
    $this->trans = $rows['trans'];
    $this->fuel = $rows['fuel'];
    $this->drive = $rows['drive'];
    $this->engine = $rows['engine'];
    $this->vin = $rows['vin'];
    $this->stocknum = $rows['stocknum'];
    $this->hit_cnt = $rows['hit_cnt'];
    $this->is_sold = $rows['is_sold'];
    $this->country_name = $rows['country_name'];
    $this->price = number_format($rows['price'], 2, '.', ',');
    $this->showprice = CURRENCY . number_format($rows['price'], 2, '.', ',');
    $this->expiry_date = date("m/d/Y", $rows['expiry_date']);
```

Comment: can we have more code before and after this line?

Comment: It means you are accidentally using something like `$function()` with the `$` prepended to the function name, where `$function` isn't defined or does not correspond to a string. I don't see such a thing here though...

Comment: The other common culprit is accidentally using parentheses for array indexing instead of brackets.

Comment: @zerocrates but it's not this case. the line 222 looks legit.

Comment: hey guys i've added more detail

Comment: Good lord, that's some **insane** indentation.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093305/fatal-error-function-name-must-be-a-string

Answer (score 1):

My bet is that

```
$rows = $this->_db->_fetch_row('DB_FETCH_ASSOC');
```

should be

```
$rows = $this->_db->fetch_row('DB_FETCH_ASSOC');
```

I don't know your database class, but if query() and num_rows() don't start with an underscore, fetch_row() probably shouldn't either. Wouldn't explain the line number too, though...

Answer (score 0):

*$this->showprice = CURRENCY . number_format($rows['price'], 2, '.', ',');*

Concating a define can cause some weird behavior, maybe this is where it is having a problem?